# What programming language for steganography?

Tags: steganography

I will be working on a year-long research project on steganography. It will use animations and I was wondering what programming language would best be suited for this task? Things to consider are speed and ease of use. Languages I have heard are usually used

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given your broad requirements, I can only suggest whatever language you already know. It's sort of like saying "what language should I use to shift bits?".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use pretty much any language to do this.  As long as you can modify the actual bits of the image, you can embed something in it.